# sx:autocompleter onchange not calling JQuery function

Tags: jquery, json, struts2

I'm using Struts2+Spring MVC+Hibernate and I'm trying to create a dependent drop-down menu.  However, my JQuery function is only being called on the page startup, and not when an option is selected in the first menu.  The organization drop-down menu is working fine.  Here is the **relevant** code:

**Search.jsp**

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>


<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function loadFacilities(value){
   $("#facilitySelect").get(0).options.length = 0;
   $("#facilitySelect").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Loading facilities", "-1");
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "DependentFacility",
      data: "{organizationID:" + value+ "}",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg){
          $("#facilitySelect").get(0).options.length = 0;
          $("#facilitySelect").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select facility", "-1");

          $.each(msg.d, function(index, item){
             $("#facilitySelect").get(0).options[$("#facilitySelect").get(0).options.length] = new Options (item.Display, item.Value); 
          });
      },
      error: function(){
          $("#facilitySelect").get(0).options.length = 0;
          alert("Failed to load facilities");
      }

   });
 });
 </script> 
 </head>



 <div class="element">
<p class="title"><s:property value="getText('global.a_search_screen')" /></p>
<s:form name="ASearch" action="aSearchList" type="POST">
    <p class="content">
        <table class="topSearch">
        //Some Table stuff was here

              <td >
                    <s:url id="organizationList" action="getListOfOrganizations" />
                    <sx:autocompleter href="%{organizationList}" name="organizations" onchange="loadFacilities(this.value)" keyValue="0" value="---- SELECT ONE-----"/>

                </td>
                <td >
                    <select id="facilitySelect"  name="selectedFacility" ></select>
                </td>
```

**Struts.xml**

```
  <action name="DependentFacility" class="facilityActions">
   <result type="json">
    <param name="root">facility</param>
   </result>
  </action>
```

**FacilityActions.java**

```
public class FacilityActions implements ModelDriven<FacilityVO> {

FacilityService facilityService;
private Map<String, String> facilities = new HashMap<String, String>();
FacilityVO facility = new FacilityVO();

public void setFacilityService(FacilityService facilityService) {
    this.facilityService = facilityService;
}

public FacilityVO getModel(){
    return facility;
}

public String execute() {
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}   

public String addFacility(){
    try{
        facilityService.addFacility(facility);
        return "SUCCESS";}
    catch(Exception e){
        return "ERROR";
    }catch(Throwable t){
        return "ERROR";
    }
}

public Map<String, String> getFacilities() {

    List<FacilityVO> facilityList = facilityService.listFacilities();

    Iterator<FacilityVO> iterator = facilityList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        FacilityVO fac = iterator.next();
        facilities.put(fac.getFacilityName(), Integer.toString(fac.getFacilityId()));
    }

    return facilities;
}   

public FacilityVO getFacility(Object thing){
    System.out.println("got a thing:" + thing.toString());
    return facility;
}

public FacilityVO getFacility(){
    System.out.println("Getting facility but nothing given?");
    return facility;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Ajax and JavaScript recipes show](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ajax-and-javascript-recipes.html#AjaxandJavaScriptRecipes-Loadcharacterswhileusertypes%2528whentextsize%253E%253D3%2529) the appropriate attribute to set is `loadOnTextChange`.

Remember, these are Dojo widgets, not simple HTML controls–you can't necessarily use standard HTML attributes to modify their behavior.

If you're using JSON, see the [recipe for JSON results](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ajax-and-javascript-recipes.html#AjaxandJavaScriptRecipes-UsingtheJSONplugintogeneratethevalues%2528oneofthepossibleways%2529); it can be much simpler than you're making it.

Comment: loadOnTextChange isn't working either...  I am just using a System.out.println on the action to see if it calls again but it's only calling on startup. The link you gave his helpful and I've come across it before, but I've had trouble getting it to work with Spring MVC.

Comment: @user1287523 What does Spring MVC have to do with any of this? I don't really understand what you're trying to do--if you're trying to use jQuery with Dojo widgets, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Most of the tutorials I've seen ask me to create a new action class with both classes included.  However I cannot implement two different VO files.
I am aware I'm doing it wrong as I'm fairly new to this.  I was hoping if I show my code I could get advice on what do to.

Comment: @user1287523 I don't understand what you're saying about VO files. I really don't know why you'd use both Spring MVC and S2 at the same time, either--pick one. As far as I can tell the issue is that you're trying to use Dojo widgets with jQuery, which is non-sensical.

Comment: I've inherited this project which uses Struts 2 + Spring MVC + Hibernate unfortunately.  The jsp pages not using the dependent dropdowns also used the dojo autocompleter widget, so to maintain consistency I am forced to use it for all future pages.  I've tried to use the simple struts s:select tag with jQuery but I'm having difficulties with my iterator when I use that.  The sj:select tag is not giving me any response.

Comment: @user1287523 Why are you trying to use jQuery with the Dojo tags? Do you understand what I'm saying about how that's a bad idea? Dojo widgets aren't simple HTML things you can manipulate with jQuery. It's a completely separate, and very different, JavaScript GUI framework. I don't understand how/why Spring MVC is involved--combining two completely different MVC frameworks in a single app is bizarre, but ultimately not related to the question at all.

Comment: I understand what you mean.  Would I be able to do this instead with the s:select tags?

Comment: @user1287523 I guess, or you could just follow the recipe and use Dojo--just depends what you need.